# React page showing many errors when using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

As I said in the title, when I run React app it shows many errors in it which occur on the browser only. There are no errors in the terminal.
These errors only occur when I use `react-router-dom`. When I comment out the import the errors are gone and the app loads correctly.

I have already tried reinstalling and updating react and `react-router-dom` and tried creating a new app and copy pasting the files in it.

Is there any solution ? Also is there any way I can route `onclick button` without using `react-router-dom` ?

This is the list of errors on the browser.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
useContext
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1616
  1613 |     }
  1614 |   }
  1615 | 
> 1616 |   return dispatcher.useContext(Context);
  1617 | }
  1618 | function useState(initialState) {
  1619 |   var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
View compiled
useHistory
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/modules/hooks.js:18
  15 |     );
  16 |   }
  17 | 
> 18 |   return useContext(HistoryContext);
  19 | }
  20 | 
  21 | export function useLocation() {
View compiled
Login
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/src/components/Login.js:6
  3 | import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
  4 | 
  5 | export default function Login() {
> 6 |   const history =  useHistory();
  7 | 
  8 |   const [firstNameReg, setfirstName] = useState('')
  9 |   const [lastNameReg, setLastName] = useState('')
View compiled
renderWithHooks
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14803
  14800 |   }
  14801 | }
  14802 | 
> 14803 | var children = Component(props, secondArg); // Check if there was a render phase update
        | ^  14804 | 
  14805 | if (workInProgress.expirationTime === renderExpirationTime) {
  14806 |   // Keep rendering in a loop for as long as render phase updates continue to
View compiled
mountIndeterminateComponent
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17482
  17479 | 
  17480 |   setIsRendering(true);
  17481 |   ReactCurrentOwner$1.current = workInProgress;
> 17482 |   value = renderWithHooks(null, workInProgress, Component, props, context, renderExpirationTime);
        | ^  17483 |   setIsRendering(false);
  17484 | } // React DevTools reads this flag.
  17485 | 
View compiled
beginWork
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18596
  18593 | switch (workInProgress.tag) {
  18594 |   case IndeterminateComponent:
  18595 |     {
> 18596 |       return mountIndeterminateComponent(current, workInProgress, workInProgress.type, renderExpirationTime);
        | ^  18597 |     }
  18598 | 
  18599 |   case LazyComponent:
View compiled
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:188
  185 |     window.event = windowEvent;
  186 |   }
  187 | 
> 188 |   func.apply(context, funcArgs);
      | ^  189 |   didError = false;
  190 | } // Create a global error event handler. We use this to capture the value
  191 | // that was thrown. It's possible that this error handler will fire more
View compiled
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237
  234 | // errors, it will trigger our global error handler.
  235 | 
  236 | evt.initEvent(evtType, false, false);
> 237 | fakeNode.dispatchEvent(evt);
      | ^  238 | 
  239 | if (windowEventDescriptor) {
  240 |   Object.defineProperty(window, 'event', windowEventDescriptor);
View compiled
invokeGuardedCallback
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:292
  289 | function invokeGuardedCallback(name, func, context, a, b, c, d, e, f) {
  290 |   hasError = false;
  291 |   caughtError = null;
> 292 |   invokeGuardedCallbackImpl$1.apply(reporter, arguments);
  293 | }
  294 | /**
  295 |  * Same as invokeGuardedCallback, but instead of returning an error, it stores
View compiled
beginWork$1
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23203
  23200 | } // Run beginWork again.
  23201 | 
  23202 | 
> 23203 | invokeGuardedCallback(null, beginWork, null, current, unitOfWork, expirationTime);
        | ^  23204 | 
  23205 | if (hasCaughtError()) {
  23206 |   var replayError = clearCaughtError(); // `invokeGuardedCallback` sometimes sets an expando `_suppressLogging`.
View compiled
performUnitOfWork
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22154
  22151 | 
  22152 | if ( (unitOfWork.mode & ProfileMode) !== NoMode) {
  22153 |   startProfilerTimer(unitOfWork);
> 22154 |   next = beginWork$1(current, unitOfWork, renderExpirationTime$1);
        | ^  22155 |   stopProfilerTimerIfRunningAndRecordDelta(unitOfWork, true);
  22156 | } else {
  22157 |   next = beginWork$1(current, unitOfWork, renderExpirationTime$1);
View compiled
workLoopSync
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22130
  22127 | function workLoopSync() {
  22128 |   // Already timed out, so perform work without checking if we need to yield.
  22129 |   while (workInProgress !== null) {
> 22130 |     workInProgress = performUnitOfWork(workInProgress);
  22131 |   }
  22132 | }
  22133 | /** @noinline */
View compiled
performSyncWorkOnRoot
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21756
  21753 | 
  21754 | do {
  21755 |   try {
> 21756 |     workLoopSync();
        | ^  21757 |     break;
  21758 |   } catch (thrownValue) {
  21759 |     handleError(root, thrownValue);
View compiled
scheduleUpdateOnFiber
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21188
  21185 |   // root inside of batchedUpdates should be synchronous, but layout updates
  21186 |   // should be deferred until the end of the batch.
  21187 | 
> 21188 |   performSyncWorkOnRoot(root);
        | ^  21189 | } else {
  21190 |   ensureRootIsScheduled(root);
  21191 |   schedulePendingInteractions(root, expirationTime);
View compiled
updateContainer
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24373
  24370 |   }
  24371 | 
  24372 |   enqueueUpdate(current$1, update);
> 24373 |   scheduleWork(current$1, expirationTime);
  24374 |   return expirationTime;
  24375 | }
  24376 | function getPublicRootInstance(container) {
View compiled
(anonymous function)
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24758
  24755 | 
  24756 | 
  24757 |   unbatchedUpdates(function () {
> 24758 |     updateContainer(children, fiberRoot, parentComponent, callback);
        | ^  24759 |   });
  24760 | } else {
  24761 |   fiberRoot = root._internalRoot;
View compiled
unbatchedUpdates
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21903
  21900 | executionContext |= LegacyUnbatchedContext;
  21901 | 
  21902 | try {
> 21903 |   return fn(a);
        | ^  21904 | } finally {
  21905 |   executionContext = prevExecutionContext;
  21906 | 
View compiled
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24757
  24754 |   } // Initial mount should not be batched.
  24755 | 
  24756 | 
> 24757 |   unbatchedUpdates(function () {
        | ^  24758 |     updateContainer(children, fiberRoot, parentComponent, callback);
  24759 |   });
  24760 | } else {
View compiled
render
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24840
  24837 |     }
  24838 |   }
  24839 | 
> 24840 |   return legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer(null, element, container, false, callback);
  24841 | }
  24842 | function unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer(parentComponent, element, containerNode, callback) {
  24843 |   if (!isValidContainer(containerNode)) {
View compiled
Module../src/index.js
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/src/index.js:6
  3 | import './index.css';
  4 | import App from './App';
  5 | 
> 6 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
  7 | 
  8 | // If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
  9 | // unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
View compiled
__webpack_require__
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:4396:18
__webpack_require__
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/webpack/bootstrap:785
  782 | };
  783 | 
  784 | // Execute the module function
> 785 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  786 | 
  787 | // Flag the module as loaded
  788 | module.l = true;
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
E:/Web Development/WT min project React/my-app/client/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:65
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Resume from "./components/Resume";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import "./App.css";
import {BrowserRouter , Route} from "react-router-dom";


function App () {  
  return (
      <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />}/>
        <Route exact path="/resume" element={<Resume />}/>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
        <Login />
        {/* <Resume /> */}
        </>
        );
      };

export default App;
```

Login.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Login() {
  const history =  useHistory();

  const [firstNameReg, setfirstName] = useState('')
  const [lastNameReg, setLastName] = useState('')
  const [emReg, setem] = useState('')
  const [phReg, setph] = useState('')
  const [usernameReg, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [passReg, setpass] = useState('')

  

  function register() {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/register', { firstName: firstNameReg, lastName: lastNameReg, em: emReg, ph: phReg, username: usernameReg, pass: passReg });
  }

  return (
    <div>
          <form className="row g-3 col-6 offset-3">
  <div className="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputName" className="form-label">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputName" onChange={(e) => {
          setfirstName(e.target.value);
    }} />
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputLast" className="form-label">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputLast"
    onChange={(e) => {
      setLastName(e.target.value);
}}
    />
  </div>
  <div className="col-12">
    <label for="inputEmail" className="form-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" className="form-control" id="inputEmail"
    onChange={(e) => {
      setem(e.target.value);
}}
    />
  </div>
  <div className="col-12">
    <label for="inputPhone" className="form-label">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputPhone"
    onChange={(e) => {
      setph(e.target.value);
}}
    />
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputUser" className="form-label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputUser"
    onChange={(e) => {
      setUsername(e.target.value);
}}
    />
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-6">
    <label for="inputPass" className="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPass" className="form-control"
    onChange={(e) => {
      setpass(e.target.value);
}}
    />
  </div>
  <div className="col-12 offset-5">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={history('/resume')
  }>Sign in</button>
  </div>
</form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Where have you defined routes for your app?

Comment: I have defined it in App.js

Comment: You've uploaded same pictures for app.js and login.js..

Comment: Yes sorry for that I just edited it. Please check it now.

Comment: Don't add pictures without pasting code please. Paste the error stack trace and messages.

Comment: You are mixing `react-router` v5 and v6 components, exports, and syntax. First, figure out what version you *actually* have installed by running `npm list react-router react-router-dom` from the project's directory, *then* depending on version follow ***that*** versions API documentation. Figure out the version and report back.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap Route components with Routes and BrowserRouter should wrap the Routes

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

<BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
         // other routes here...
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Also, route component now doesn't have exact prop, so no need to add it

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but it did not work

Comment: @rutvij Are you still getting the same error like your screenshot above?

Comment: Yes I added the list of errors in the question now. That whole lis comes up when I use react-router-dom. When I remove it the page works properly but without the navigation.

Comment: @Rutvij Remove the <Login /> you've added after <Header /> and see if it removes the error

Comment: @Rutvij in the picture you added before for Login.js, you were not using useHistory why are you using it now, useHistory() is removed from v6 react-router-dom. You should use useNavigate hook

Comment: Actually I after uninstalling and installing react-router-dom it's showing that useNavigate is not exporting from react-router-dom so that's why I used useHistory(). Also yeah the header is visible and the errors are gone after removing <Login />.